# Accepting a reference as a parameter - when and how describe a contract between classes

Tags: c++

I am looking for best practices for describing contracts regarding an object's lifetime. Let's consider:

```
// AInterface.hpp
struct AInterface {};

// A.hpp
struct A : public AInterface
{
  A(int& a_, const int& b_)
  : a(a_)
  , b(b_)
  {}

  int& a;
  int b;
};

// AFactoryInterface.hpp
struct AFactoryInterface
{
  virtual std::shared_ptr<AInterface> create(int& a, const int& b) = 0;
};

// AFactory.hpp
struct AFactory : public AFactoryInterface
{
  std::shared_ptr<AInterface> create(int& a, const int& b) override
  {
    return std::make_shared<A>(a, b);
  }
};
```

Do we assume by default that the lifetime of `int& a` is longer than the existence of an instance of `A` (but `const int& b` may be shorter) unless documented otherwise?

Or rather everytime when we accept a reference, we must precisely state how long caller must keep it?

If any documentation here should be required, where it should be placed?
`AFactory::create`, `AFactoryInterface::create`, `A::A`, everywhere?

Comment: You cannot safely store a reference as a class member (even if you have 100% control over the lifetime of the original it's a bad idea). You should be storing a smart pointer to the original instead

Comment: @UnholySheep, I understand that choosing shared_ptr might be better but we store references to objects that have numerous instances. Why shouldn't I store references in a case when I have 100% control over the lifetime of the original object?

Comment: You surely can do it like this. In single-threaded code, this still is maintainable, provided it's documented well and I would it document at every function that takes the reference and creates an object of this special type using it (constructor + factories). But in case you are working multithreaded, shared/weak_ptr really should be considered instead.